# RC Differentiator circuit with pulsating DC voltage

Tags: circuit-design, pulse, waveform

The circuit shown in the picture is a RC differentiator circuit whose output is a pure sine wave while the input is pulsating DC. I wonder how the circuit converts pulsating DC input voltage to a pure output sine wave by using a resistor and a capacitor.I need a fair expalianation that how it has become[image] possible ?

Comment: Perhaps your interpretation of input vs. output signals is incorrect? You get a sinusoidal output *only* for a sinusoidal input.

Comment: what if the input is ac superimposed on dc ?

Comment: The input is an AC signal plus a DC offset. The cap blocks the dc offset and only allows the AC component, which is a pure sinusoidal input, to make it through.

Comment: (DC + Sine) input yields (0DC + Sine output). Some phase shift of output relative to input occurs for sine waveforms. The red pulsating DC input is a separate case.

Comment: Sorry, but text in your question and draw mismatch. The draw contains two signals (square and sinus) pointing to the power source instead of a square one; other two pointing to the output instead of sinus. To be clarified.

Comment: avoid square. just talk about sine wave

Answer (score 1):

The circuit shown in the picture is a RC differentiator circuit whose output is a pure sine wave when the input signal is a pure sinewave, but the output sinewave has been shifted down so it has zero DC content.

The circuit shown in the picture is a RC differentiator circuit whose output is a pulse waveform when the input signal is a pulse waveform, but the output pulse waveform has been shifted down so it has zero DC content. Note the positive and negative peaks are not equal as the duty cycle is not 50%.

The diagram does not show the slight distortion that will occur to the top and bottom of the pulse waveform as it passes through a RC highpass filter whose time constant is much longer than the period of the signal, as is obviously the case here. When the signal period is << filter time constant, the filter only really acts as a DC removal block.